# I miss you like I (have) never missed someone else

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Which one of the following phrases is correct? I'm unsure about using present perfect or not.

> I miss you like I've never missed someone else.
>
> I miss you like I never missed someone else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) The general principle is "avoid unnecessary use of Perfect forms". But in some contexts (such as the one cited here) we often / normally ***do*** use it.

Answer (score 4):

Present perfect sounds more natural. It suggests “up until this moment”, while the past tense doesn’t have that connotation. The past tense version sounds like it might be referring to one specific moment in the past when the speaker never missed another person- that doesn’t really make sense.

I’d also replace *someone* with *anyone*; *someone* usually refers to one particular person, while *anyone* refers to any person at all.